# PWM with alternative load

Tags: arduino, pwm

I want to drive an ~220V incandescent bulb with arduino's pwm, any suggestion about the stage to put between them.

Comment: -1 for no prior research whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incandescent bulbs are normally dimmed using triac phase-angle control. It's a form of PWM but synchronised with the mains frequency.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phase angle control. By delaying the turn-on point in the mains half-cycle power can be reduced from close to 100% to close to 0%.*

A triac is used to control the AC. The triac is triggered by the micro-controller but using an opto-isolator with > 1,000 electrical isolation for safety. Since the dimmer has to be synchronised with the mains a zero-crossing detection circuit is also required.

Russell McMahon's answer to [Arduino 230 V light bulb dimming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59615/arduino-230v-light-bulb-dimming) may be of help to you.